# Symfony 2 Get original data of entity from entity manager

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, sonata-admin, sonata

I am using Sonata admin bundle for my application all works well,In my application i have users and admin,admin can add/edit/delete the users when i am trying to update a user there is a problem the password data is overrided from user table. i have overrided the `preUpdate` method of admin controller ,I got `$object` which has an instance of user entity manager so if user leaves to update password and saves data the password is lost.

```
public function preUpdate($object)
{
    $Password = $object->getUserPassword();
    if (!empty($Password)) { /* i check here if user has enter password then update it goes well*/
        $salt = md5(time());
        $encoderservice = $this->getConfigurationPool()->getContainer()->get('security.encoder_factory');
        $User = new User();
        $encoder = $encoderservice->getEncoder($User);
        $encoded_pass = $encoder->encodePassword($Password, $salt);
        $object->setUserSalt($salt)->setUserPassword($encoded_pass);
    } else { /* here i try to set the old password if user not enters the new password but fails */
        $object->setUserPassword($object->getUserPassword());
    }
}
```

When i try to set `$object->setUserPassword($object->getUserPassword());` it gets null and updates the password as null its not getting the edit data i have tried to get the repository (below) again to get the password but no luck its getting the same

```
$DM = $this->getConfigurationPool()->getContainer()->get('Doctrine')->getManager()->getRepository("...")->find(id here);
```

Is there a way i can access the original data of current entity in entity manager

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can access the original data by getting doctrine's **Unit of Work**.As from docs

> You can get direct access to the Unit of Work by calling
> EntityManager#getUnitOfWork(). This will return the UnitOfWork
> instance the EntityManager is currently using.An array containing the
> original data of entity

Grab the password from Unit of Work and use in your setter method

```
public function preUpdate($object)
{

    $DM = $this->getConfigurationPool()->getContainer()->get('Doctrine')->getManager();
    $uow = $DM->getUnitOfWork();
    $OriginalEntityData = $uow->getOriginalEntityData( $object );
    $Password = $object->getUserPassword();
    if (!empty($Password)) { /* i check here if user has enter password then update it goes well*/
        $salt = md5(time());
        $encoderservice = $this->getConfigurationPool()->getContainer()->get('security.encoder_factory');
        $User = new User();
        $encoder = $encoderservice->getEncoder($User);
        $encoded_pass = $encoder->encodePassword($Password, $salt);
        $object->setUserSalt($salt)->setUserPassword($encoded_pass);
    } else { /* here i try to set the old password if user not enters the new password but fails */
        $object->setUserPassword($OriginalEntityData['Password']);/* your property name for password field */
    }
}
```

Hope it works fine

[**Direct access to a Unit of Work**](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/working-with-objects.html#direct-access-to-a-unit-of-work)

Comment: The link is broken

Answer (score 0):

Reset entity in entity manage, example for `onFlush` event

```
  /**
     * @param OnFlushEventArgs $args
     *
     * @throws \Doctrine\ORM\ORMException
     * @throws \Doctrine\ORM\OptimisticLockException
     */
    public function onFlush(OnFlushEventArgs  $args)
    {
        $em = $args->getEntityManager();
        $uow = $em->getUnitOfWork();

        foreach ($uow->getScheduledEntityUpdates() as $keyEntity => $entity) {
            if ($entity instanceof Bill) {
                $em->refresh($entity);
                $this->createPdfs($entity);

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -3):

```
$this->getConfigurationPool()
     ->getContainer()
     ->get('Doctrine')
     ->getRepository("...")
     ->find(id here);
```

So leave out the `getManager()` part;